# Error al conectar en MYSQL con php

Tags: php, mysql

este es mi código de php pero estoy teniendo esta série de errores en el código

```
Warning: Packets out of order. Expected 0 received 1. Packet size=74 in C:\xampp\htdocs\imagenes\conectar.php on line 8

Warning: mysqli::__construct(): MySQL server has gone away in C:\xampp\htdocs\imagenes\conectar.php on line 8

Warning: mysqli::__construct(): Error while reading greeting packet. PID=2836 in C:\xampp\htdocs\imagenes\conectar.php on line 8

Warning: mysqli::__construct(): (HY000/2006): MySQL server has gone away in C:\xampp\htdocs\imagenes\conectar.php on line 8
```

Y este es mí código para conectar

```
<?php
$database = "142.44.252.245"; #localhost
$dbusername = "usuario"; #username of phpmyadmin
$dbpassword = "contraseña";  #password of phpmyadmin
$dbname = "database";  #database name
 
#connection string
$conn = new mysqli($database,$dbusername,$dbpassword,$dbname); //línea 8
?>
```

¿Cómo puedo resolver esta cosa?

Comment: Los comentarios no deben usarse para discusiones extendidas; esta conversación ha sido [trasladada a un chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/133014/discussion-on-question-by-user264129-error-al-conectar-en-mysql-con-php).

Answer (score 0):

En el panel de control de XAMPP busca el botón de configuración de MySQL (MariaDB):

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Busca las siguientes opciones o agrégalas en caso de que no aparezcan:

Incrementa el valor de `max_allowed_packet`, prueba con un número grande, tal vez 128M o, incluso, 256M; ejemplo:

```
max_allowed_packet=128M
```

Si manejas muchas conexiones en cada petición, probablemente esa sea la causa del problema y tengas que incrementar `max_conecctions`, generalmente establecida en un número bajo, prueba con 1024:

```
max_connections=1024
```

Guarda el archivo de configuración y reinicia el servicio. En teoría, ya deberías poder trabajar sin problemas, pero te recomiendo revisar el flujo de tus scripts para ver qué es lo que ocasiona el uso excesivo de recursos.

Comment: No funciona, sigo teniendo el mismo problema

Comment: @user264129, prueba números mayores para cada opción y, también ten en cuenta que XAMPP fue creado para ambiente de desarrollo y no se recomienda usar en producción, es mejor instalar cada componente por separado, tanto por seguridad como por estabilidad.

Comment: No funciona, el archivo de imagen pesa 1.74mb, en mi código no tengo algún máximo de peso, ¿es obligatório añadir un máximo?